# NameError: undefined local variable or method `deploy_to' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, centos

I have a problem I can not understand where is the error. When I run **setup mine --trace**.
Jumps out here such error:

---

**Invoke setup (first_time)**

**Invoke environment (first_time)**

**Execute environment**

***!     :environment is DEPRECATED! Please use local_environment and remote_environment***

**Execute setup**

**Invoke ssh_keyscan_repo (first_time)**

**Execute ssh_keyscan_repo**

**mina aborted!**

**NameError: undefined local variable or method `deploy_to' for main:Object**

**Did you mean?  deploy**

**/home/sergiusdk/phonebook-api/config/deploy.rb:14:in `block in '**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `block in execute'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `each'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:251:in `execute'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke_with_call_chain'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/task.rb:181:in `invoke'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mina-1.2.3/lib/mina/application.rb:16:in `run'**

**/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mina-1.2.3/bin/mina:4:in `'**

**/usr/local/bin/mina:23:in `load'**

**/usr/local/bin/mina:23:in `'**

**Tasks: TOP => setup**

---

Here is my **deploy.rb**:

---

```js
require 'mina/bundler'

require 'mina/rails'

require 'mina/git'


set :domain, '192.120.4.241'

set :user, 'sergiusdk'

set :deploy_to, '/home/sergiusdk/phonebook-api'

set :repository, 'https://github.com/phonebook-api_sergiusdk/phonebook-api.git'

set :branch, 'master'


set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/puma.rb', 'log']

task :setup => :environment do

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]


  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/puma"]

  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/puma"]


  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"]

  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit '#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml', 'secrets.yml' and puma.rb."]

end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."

task :deploy => :environment do

  deploy do

    # Put things that will set up an empty directory into a fully set-up

    # instance of your project.

    invoke :'git:clone'

    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'

    invoke :'bundle:install'

    #invoke :'rails:db_migrate'

    #invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'

    #invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

  end

end
```

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `deploy_to' for main:Object

Did you mean? deploy

Comment: Just downgrade your mina version and then try again